# ListView Item not clickable

Tags: android, listview

im trying to make an activity that searches a DB based on an input string and then returns the results in a list view.  All this is working however, My listview items are not clickable. I have tried changing the focus and clickable attributes but nothing has worked so far.

Main XML (add_friend_layout.xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" >


 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/AddFriendHeaderLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_SearchFriend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_SearchFriend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
            android:text="Search" >

        </Button>   

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dip"  
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/AddFriendHeaderLayout"
        android:id="@+id/searchFriendFooterLayout">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ListView XML (single_listview_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" >


</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Java Function (SearchFriendActivity.java):

```
public class SearchFriendActivity extends ListActivity {

//Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private Button bt_searchFriend;
private EditText et_Search_String;
private ListView tv_listview;

String[] arrFriends;
String[] arrUserId;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try{
        setContentView(R.layout.add_friend_layout);


        bt_searchFriend= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_SearchFriend);
        et_Search_String = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_SearchFriend);
        tv_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tv_list);


        String searchString="";

        //searchString = String.valueOf(et_Search_String.getText());
        Log.i ("log_search","value of searchString: " + searchString);

        bt_searchFriend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try{



                    searchFriends aTask = new searchFriends();

                             aTask.execute(String.valueOf(et_Search_String.getText()));
                    String rResult = aTask.get();

                    // Convert aResult to array
                    arrFriends = convertJSONData(rResult);
                    arrUserId = convertJSONDataToUserArray(rResult);


                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                                                    (getBaseContext(),       
                                                    R.layout.single_listview_layout, 
                            R.id.tv_list,
                            arrFriends));

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e ("log_search_load",e.toString());
                }
            }
        });


        tv_listview = getListView();


        //handler for List Item click
        tv_listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Friend request sent for " + 
                                            ((TextView) view).getText(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.i("log_search_listclick", "Listview clicked");
            }
        });

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e ("log_search_load2",e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, don't use focusable and clickable. When you use `setOnclick` or another they are auto creating.

Secondly, remove try cache blog then start application. Because when the problem created program will contining and you can't understand where is the problem.

===>Thirdly<====
you are used (`tv_listview=`...) second twice

1. `tv_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tv_list);`
2. `tv_listview = getListView();`

then you are trying `tv_listview.setOnItemClickListener....`. If second view is not first view seton not working on "R.id.tv_list".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried removing the tv_listview = getListView() but that did not help.  I removed the try/catch block as you suggested and the app crashes.  I have isolated it to the creation of the  tv_listview.setOnItemClickListener.  If i remove it, the app runs fine.  If I add it back in, the app crashes with a nullpointerexception even if the function is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: OK - so i figured out that I was linking tv_listview to the textview object in the row def xml file instead of the list view.  Once I fixed that, the nullpointexcept was gone.  Im still not able to get the list view to execute  the onclick function.

Comment: okey now try clear Toast message. Then run application. If you don't see any problem , problem in the Toast (==>getApplicationContext()<==,......);

Comment: I think the problem must be something to do with the xml definition.  I found that it works if i change the setListAdapter call to use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 instead of my single_listview_layout.xml.  Im still not sure why though.

Comment: when you are use add item in listview's arrayAdapter, arrayAdapter calling setText("....");. But your tw_listView is LinearLayout. When calling setText program creating exception. So your singleRow layout must extend TextView or Button or another can settext Views. Convert your tw_listView to Textview.